# Fill some fields from other module based on many2one field

Tags: odoo-13

I have 3 fields

```
 Pick_no= fields.many2one(stock.picking)
Partner_id= field.char
Location_id=field.char
```

I want to auto fill partner and location fields based on the selected pick_id.
What should I use onchange or depends?

Answer (score 0):

IMO You may use onchange() method.

Need to change field datatype. Go to stock.picking model and verify datatype. In your case, you declared with `char`. It is not wrong but not advisable. If you want to keep `char` then assign char value, not ID.

```
partner_id = fields.Many2one(res.partner)
location_id = fields.Many2one(stock.location)
```